# CMake command displays error at "CMakeLists.txt" with FindCEF

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a problem when executing the following command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
```

The error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:155 (find_package):
    By not providing "FindCEF.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CEF", but
    CMake did not find one.

    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CEF" with any of
    the following names:

    CEFConfig.cmake
    cef-config.cmake

    Add the installation prefix of "CEF" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "CEF_DIR"
    to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CEF" provides a
    separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Okay … So did you do as the error suggests?

Comment: Yeah I checked the file 

# Load the CEF configuration (executes FindCEF.cmake).
find_package(CEF REQUIRED)

the line is this but I did not get how to solve it.. @ChrisMM

Comment: You need to add the path to CEF either to your Windows PATH environment variable, or the CMAKE variables it mentions … If you use CMake GUI, you can specify the value quite easily. You should only have to once. Probably a way through command line, but I don't use CMake through command line enough to know the syntax.

Comment: The error suggests "*set "CEF_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files*". Did you do this?

Comment: It is already added to the environment variable as example\cmake-3.16.2-win64-x64\bin Could it be a bug at this specific version? @ChrisMM

Comment: `example\cmake-3.16.2-win64-x64\bin ` I would not expect that to be the correct path. or is `examlple` something different that you did not type? Does this folder contain either of the files listed in the error message?

Comment: If you have config files for the CEF library add the path to the config files to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. if you have a custom `FindCEF.cmake` module file add the path to it to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Comment: ***I found a helpful link will give it a try*** The link seems to be about a person who got this error because they did not have CEF built or installed on their system in the first place. If you have these files then its installed on your windows machine but cmake can't find it because it does not know where to look.